# Removing the line from the top bar from wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

**FOLLOWING ISSUE BEING RESOLVED NOW:**

I am working for the first time on wordpress currently i am facing just a small issue of adding a top bar which will come from the following code. In simple html its working perfectly fine but its creating some error when i put this code in the index file on the the top of the index.php page. All i want to do is that the top bar should appear generically on all the other pages being used in the theme and appear perfectly fine kindly let me know which one is the efficient place to put the following piece of code.

Note: I am using by default theme by wordpress

Comment: I edited the header.php file and its now appearing in all the pages but there is only one problem there is a line appearing on it you can see that on the image i attached . http://caremerge.us/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to display options for the editors, you should look into the WordPress toolbar:
http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/inside-the-wordpress-toolbar/

If you want to edit the header for all users. The theme will like have a header.php which you can edit. The recommended way to do this would be to make your changes in a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: all i am trying to do that my top bar should appear beneath the by default wordpress dashboard bar that's all

Comment: I edited the header.php file and its now appearing in all the pages but there is only one problem there is a line appearing on it you can see that on the image i attached

Comment: The line must be added in your style sheet somewhere. Have a look at the element with FireBug or a similar tool.

Comment: i;ll be very thankful to you if you identify that kinly visit this url i tried but could not find . Thanks, 

http://caremerge.us/wordpress/

Comment: Quick fix: just add a margin-top: -28px (give or take a few points) to the header div. Looks like the position: absolute is part of the prob.